# Sharing / Liking an object in a tabbed facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I have a facebook application which will run as a Page Tab.

The page will include items such as videos etc..

I want to give the users the ability to like/share the videos.  If the URL for the videos is [http://mydomain.com/pagetab/video-1.html], how does the user get directed back to the facebook page tab when someone else clicks on the shared link in a news feed or from someone's wall?  Won't they always go directly to http://mydomain.com/pagetab/video-1.html ?

Or is there a way to specify a URL with deep linking such as:
http://facebook.com/pagename/pagetab/page ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about liking this URL, but you can deep link in Facebook tabs using the app_data param in the query string and then within your app you can extract that from the signed_request (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)